# Pandas - Variation on filling NaN - What's an elegant and pythonic way to do this?

Tags: python, pandas

Good evening

In the dataframe below, column `'c'` has a few NaNs

What is a nice, pythonic way to fill the first N `nans` with a value and the remaining `nans` with another one

(example: fill the first 3 `nans` with the value `10` and the remaining 2 `nans` with the value `20`)

Thanks

```
   a  b   c
a  5  5 NaN
b  5  8   8
c  0  1 NaN
d  8  5   6
e  1  6 NaN
f  2  5   8
g  6  5   5
h  0  1   3
i  7  3 NaN
j  2  6 NaN
```

Edit I - This is one (un-pythonic) way:

```
nan_number = df['c'].isnull().cumsum()[df['c'].isnull()] 
df['c'][nan_number.index[nan_number<=3]] = 10
df['c'][nan_number.index[nan_number>3]] = 20
```

Edit II - This starts to look better:

```
nan_rows = df.index[df['c'].isnull()]
df.loc[nan_rows[:3], 'c'] = 10  
df.loc[nan_rows[3:], 'c'] = 20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna), this takes a `limit` param:

```
In [75]:

df = df.fillna(10,limit=3)
df = df.fillna(20)
df
Out[75]:
   a  b   c
a  5  5  10
b  5  8   8
c  0  1  10
d  8  5   6
e  1  6  10
f  2  5   8
g  6  5   5
h  0  1   3
i  7  3  20
j  2  6  20
```

If you prefer a one-liner you can chain the calls to `fillna`:

```
In [80]:

df = df.fillna(10,limit=3).fillna(20)
df
Out[80]:
   a  b   c
a  5  5  10
b  5  8   8
c  0  1  10
d  8  5   6
e  1  6  10
f  2  5   8
g  6  5   5
h  0  1   3
i  7  3  20
j  2  6  20
```

Comment: I think `limit` has another meaning (docstring says "Maximum size gap to forward or backward fill") and it just accidentally worked here.

Comment: @joris I did wonder about that so I thought what would happen and it did what the OP asked for, I agree that it does seem to accidentally work

Comment: after some testing, I agree it does seem to work here. But then *or* the docsting is incorrect *or* there is a bug in the implementation

Comment: @EdChum  Very creative.  You can also shorten it to one liner: df = df.fillna(10, limit=3).fillna(20)

Comment: @Alexander yes that would work but I sometimes worry about chaining these calls but in this case it does work

Comment: Definitely works, thanks EdChum. Should I accept this? joris is right that docstring describes `limit` as somewhat different in usage.

Comment: Yes, the docstring describes `limit` for the case you use a `method` and not a `value` to fill. But will open an issue to clear out the usage of limit in this case: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10002

Comment: @joris to me this looks to me as a useful side-effect the docstrings imply this is for ffill `NaN` but I think the behaviour is consistent